# Remove stains from leather shoe

Tags: cleaning, shoes

I recently bought new shoes (leather) and wore them yesterday for the first time and today. I just spotted some dark brown stains at the toecaps of both shoes and I am sure that those weren't there when I bought them.

I have no idea what could have caused those stains. I was mostly inside at the workplace, so I don't think that this comes from mud or dirt.

Do you have an idea what it might be and how I can get rid of it without damaging the material?

[image: the shoes]

Comment: I cannot make a good judgement from the picture. I am afraid that they are traces of glue (or other product) which was used during manufacture - and you just did not notice them before. If it is possible, please go back to the store and look at the other shoes of the same make / model. I expect that they have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

They might not be the traces of glue so try this if it doesn't work then it might be the glue from the manufacturer.
Dip a cotton swab in nail polish remover or rubbing alcohol and lightly blot the stain. Don’t rub, or you could make the ink spread. Blot gently until the stain is gone. Wipe with a clean, damp cloth and dry with a towel.